# Run time efficiency of binary search using iterator parameters?

Tags: c++, iterator, binary-search

I'm searching a large vector of integers to check if the vector contains a 3, and I'm trying to work out the fastest (worse case) solution:

```
int find_me {3};

//Approach One (order vector and use a binary search)
std::vector<int> Test {1,2,3,1,1,1,4,5,4,3,1,3,2,1,5,5};
std::sort(Test.begin(), Test.end());
auto result = std::binary_search(Test.begin(), Test.end(), find_me);


//Approach Two (use lower and upper bound iterator positions in a binary search)
std::vector<int> Test {1,2,3,1,1,1,4,5,4,3,1,3,2,1,5,5};
std::sort(Test.begin(), Test.end());
auto parameter_1 = std::upper_bound(Test.begin(), Test.end(), find_me - 1);
auto parameter_2 = std::lower_bound(Test.begin(), Test.end(), find_me + 1);
auto result = std::binary_search(parameter_1, parameter_2, find_me);
```

Does using upper and lower  bounds add significant run time cost to the searching operation? Or does the decreased search range increase the runtime efficiency?

Comment: Are you going to be searching the vector repeatedly? Sorting it is a lot more expensive than just going through element by element, looking for a 3, so it only makes sense if you're going to sort once and then search repeatedly.

Comment: Also, if using `std::upper_bound` and `std::lower_bound` would improve the runtime of `std::binary_search`, `std::binary_search` would just do that itself.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm only going to be making the search a single time

Comment: Agree with @user2357112. Assuming it's a repeated search, just a normal binary search would be faster. You're making 2 extra passes to get the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: The sort is essential for the binary search to work. But if you're only going to search once, and you have no other reason for this vector to be sorted, then a linear search (with `std::find`) on the original, unsorted vector would be better.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley do you want to expand this comment into an answer and I'll accept?